# Filling/replacing nodata values of a raster layer in R

Tags: raster, r, nodata

Is there a way to fill my NoData values in R?

I have a raster that has several nodata pixels, which looks like this:
[image]

(each white dot has no data)

For the moment, the no data values are assigned -Inf:

```
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr "D:\\Users\cost_based_on_density_new.asc"
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 1
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 892
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr "gdal"
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num Inf
  .. .. ..@ max       : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr "cost_based_on_density_new"
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num -15.1
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num -7.64
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 7.19
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 12.7
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 892
  ..@ nrows   : int 658
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()
```

How can I assign a new value (ex: 10000) to these nodata pixels in R?

Comment: Try `x[!is.finite(x)] <- 10000` where `x` is the object your showed a print summary of. There's lots of other possibilities, but your question (IMO) needs to demonstrate that what you describe is actual, for this to work. Can you also try  `plot(x); points(xyFromCell(x, which(!is.finite(values(x)))), pch = "+")` `plot(is.finite(x))`, to be sure? (That's what I'd be checking ...)

Comment: That worked it seems, the no data pixels are gone after x[!is.finite(x)] <- 10000; plot(x). If you want you could write an answer and I would check it

Comment: No worries, RobertH's answer is best :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current way to do that would be

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

x <- subst(r, NA, 1000)
```

See `?terra::classify` for more complex replacement.

=== old answer ===

You are incorrect in assuming that "the no data values are assigned -Inf". (I understand that you get that idea from "@ nodatavalue : num -Inf", but that is not how it works when the driver is "gdal".)

The canonical way to change cells with NA to another value is

```
y <- reclassify(x, cbind(NA, 10000))
```

While it is possible to do

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 10000
```

I would generally discourage this approach as it is prone to memory limitation errors, and less flexible (e.g. you cannot provide a filename argument)

`is.finite` works too, because:

```
is.finite(NA)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: The documentation for raster::subs() suggests that simple swaps of one value for another are better done using raster::subs(), with raster::reclassify() reserved for changing cells falling within some interval to a new value (e.g., all cells with a value less than 50 get a value of 1). Is that guidance not true in this case?